# respond_with & Flash Notice

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have the following in one of my controllers:

```
def create

  photo.user = current_user if current_user
  flash[:notice] = "The photos was saved" if photo.save
  respond_with photo, :location => photo_path(photo)

end
```

This code works with one exception. If I access this action w/ some kind of AJAX, and then visit another page, the flash notice will get displayed. How can I only display the flash notice when responding with :html? I thought maybe you could pass a :notice => "my flash" to `respond_with` but no luck.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can put condition like:

```
flash[:notice] = "The photos was saved" if photo.save && !request.xhr?
```

Also, if some day you will decide use generated notice when responding to AJAX request,
you can use `flash.discard` to clear flash.

Answer (score -1):

Use as below:

```
respond_to do |format|
  format.html { redirect_to photo_path(photo), :notice => 'The photos was saved') }
  format.xml  { render :xml => photo, :status => :created}
end
```

Comment: That's what I had before but I'm trying to move away from `respond_to` to the more condensed `respond_with`.

Comment: Had to downvote because the answer doesn't try to answer the posters question with respect to using `respond_with`.

Comment: @LesterPeabody but it does provide a solution. And the question may have been edited after the answer (though I am not sure what happened 2 years back). I don't have a problem with a downvote, but probably more thought should be applied before you exercise it.