# Specify flash in respond_with

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, respond-with

Rails 3 has [a nice feature](http://railscasts.com/episodes/224-controllers-in-rails-3?view=asciicast) to save writing flashes on a separate line:

```
redirect_to @product, :notice => "Successfully created product."
```

It would be great with `respond_with`, but not supported. Any way to override `respond_with` to take an optional flash hash?

Comment: `respond_with` made so because it will output on different types of content. For example, what form should have flash message in XML or JSON formats? Also, you could use `render` and `redirect_to` inside `respond_with` block. See [docs](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionController/MimeResponds/respond_with).

Comment: I have a custom after_filter which puts the flash in a response header (that can be rendered in response to XHR).

Comment: see also http://stackoverflow.com/a/6205403/683157